# Hiding WordPress REST API endpoints from public viewing

Tags: wordpress, rest, http

I would like to start using the [WordPress REST API v2](http://v2.wp-api.org/) to query information from my site. I've noticed that when I visit an endpoint directly, I can see all of the data publicly. I've also seen that a lot of tutorials mention the use of test or local servers rather than live sites.

My questions are:

- Is this meant to be used on sites in production?
- Is there a security risk to allowing endpoints to be viewed by
  anyone, such as `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/` which shows all users
  registered to the site?
- Is it possible to allow only authorized users to access an endpoint?

I want to make sure that I am following best practices regarding security, so any tips would be helpful. How do others usually set up this data to be accessed by external applications without exposing too much?

Comment: see http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to hide the default endpoints by putting the following in `functions.php` and setting up custom endpoints with only the data I need displayed.

```
remove_action( 'init', '_add_extra_api_post_type_arguments', 11 );
remove_action( 'init', '_add_extra_api_taxonomy_arguments', 11 );
remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_initial_rest_routes', 0 );
```